# How to start my shapes moving after my first shape has made it's move

Tags: c#, 2d

So the problem is  that after i completed the movement of my first shape i want to start moving my other shapes but when i compile my program they move at the same time . I tried to use 2 different timers to stop the first one and start the other  but the result will be the same or one of the shapes will not move at all.
           The goal is to make an illustration of Pythagora's theorem. Here is my program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp14
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
         Bitmap myBitmap;
         Graphics g;

        int c = 147;

        private int X1Green, X2Green, Y1Green, Y2Green;//These variables are the coordinates of the Green Triangle which will be used to move it
        private int X1Blue, X2Blue;// These variables are the coordinates of the Blue Triangle which will be used to move it
        private int Y1PaleGreen, Y2PaleGreen;//These variables are the coordinates of the Pale Green Triangle which will be used to move it
        Timer timer1;
        Timer timer2;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            X1Green = 450;
            X2Green = 380;
            Y1Green = 120;
            Y2Green = 250;


            X1Blue = 380;
            X2Blue = 250;


            Y1PaleGreen = 50;
            Y2PaleGreen = 120;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Start();


            timer2 = new Timer();
            timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);
           // timer2.Start();
        }



        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Moving the Green Triangle Diagonally to the Light Blue Triangle
            if (Y1Green > 50) { Y1Green -= 3; }
            if (X1Green > 320) { X1Green -= 5; }
            if (X2Green > 250) { X2Green -= 5; }
            if (Y2Green > 180) { Y2Green -= 3; }


            Draw();

            timer2.Start();


        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Moving our Blue Triangle
            if (X1Blue < 450) { X1Blue += 2; }
            if (X2Blue < 320) { X2Blue += 2; }

            //Moving our Pale Green Triangle
            if (Y1PaleGreen < 180) { Y1PaleGreen += 4; }
            if (Y2PaleGreen < 250) { Y2PaleGreen += 4; }

          //  Draw();

        }

        private void Draw()
        {
            int a = 70;
            int b = 130;
            //double c = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(a, 2) + Math.Pow(b, 2));
            int c = 147;

              myBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

              Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            Pen mypen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);// drawing the rectangle to illustrate inside of it the theorem of Pythagoras
            g.DrawRectangle(mypen, 250, 50, 200, 200);

            SolidBrush LightBlue = new SolidBrush(Color.LightBlue);
            SolidBrush Blue = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
            SolidBrush PaleGreen = new SolidBrush(Color.PaleGreen);
            SolidBrush Green = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);







            //Drawing the the Light Blue Triangle at the top left corner of the rectangle
            g.FillPolygon(LightBlue, new Point[]{
                new Point(250,50), new Point(250,180), new Point(320,50)
            });




             pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = myBitmap;

            //Drawing the Pale Green Triangle at the top right corner of the rectangle
            g.FillPolygon(PaleGreen, new Point[] {
                  new Point(320,Y1PaleGreen), new Point( 450,Y1PaleGreen ), new Point( 450, Y2PaleGreen)
              });

            //Drawing the Green Triangle at the bottom right corner of the rectangle
            g.FillPolygon(Green, new Point[]
            {
            new Point( X1Green, Y1Green ), new Point( X1Green,Y2Green), new Point(X2Green,Y2Green)
             });

            //Drawing the Blue Triangle at the bottom left corner of the rectangle
            g.FillPolygon(Blue, new Point[]
            {
                  new Point(X1Blue,250), new Point(X2Blue,250), new Point(X2Blue,180)
            });


        }
    }
}
```

By the way the variables a, b and c i only wrote them to remind myself how much is the length of the sides of each right triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it this way:

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(Y1Green > 50 || X1Green > 320 || X2Green > 250 || Y2Green > 180))
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                timer2.Start();
                return;
            }

            // Moving the Green Triangle Diagonally to the Light Blue Triangle
            if (Y1Green > 50) { Y1Green -= 3; }
            if (X1Green > 320) { X1Green -= 5; }
            if (X2Green > 250) { X2Green -= 5; }
            if (Y2Green > 180) { Y2Green -= 3; }
            Draw();
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(X1Blue < 450 || X2Blue < 320 || Y1PaleGreen < 180 || Y2PaleGreen < 250))
            {
                timer2.Stop();
                return;
            }
            //Moving our Blue Triangle
            if (X1Blue < 450) { X1Blue += 2; }
            if (X2Blue < 320) { X2Blue += 2; }

            //Moving our Pale Green Triangle
            if (Y1PaleGreen < 180) { Y1PaleGreen += 4; }
            if (Y2PaleGreen < 250) { Y2PaleGreen += 4; }

            Draw();            
        }
```

Comment: oh my god it was that simple . Thank you  for the help i was completely stuck  since my timer stop wasn't working so i thought maybe there is another command that can help .